# Comparing the electric field at the centre of a hemispherical shell with an infinite plane

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

On p. 595 of Purcell and Morin’s *Electricity and Magnetism* (3rd edition), we obtain the result that at the centre of a hemispherical shell of uniform surface charge density $\sigma$ the electric field has magnitude $\sigma/4\epsilon_0$. Then the authors note the fact that the electric field at any point above an infinite sheet with the same charge density $\sigma$ has magnitude $\sigma/2\epsilon_0$. They write “You should convince yourself why it [the field at the centre of the hemisphere] must be smaller (consider the amount of charge subtended by a given solid angle), although the factor or 2 isn’t obvious.” Our shell is $z>0$, centered at $(0, 0, 0)$ and of radius $R$; they seem to be imagining the infinite plane $z=R$.

It is of course true that a given solid angle subtends more charge on the plane than on the shell, but the shell is nearer than the plane, so why should it be *intuitively* obvious that the field of the shell is smaller? Have they forgotten about the distance factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of the electric field created by a patch of surface charge with density $\sigma $ and area $dA$ is
$$
dE = \frac{\sigma dA}{4\pi\epsilon r^2}.
$$
But the solid angle subtended by this patch is
$$
d\Omega = \frac{dA \cos \theta}{r^2}
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the surface normal and the line between the field point and the patch of charge. And so
$$
dE = \frac{\sigma d\Omega }{4\pi\epsilon \cos \theta}.
$$

We see from this that the distance of the patch of charge doesn't matter; it's automatically accounted for by writing things in terms of the solid angle, since a patch of charge at a greater distance subtends a smaller solid angle. What does matter is the angle $\theta $, which is zero for all surface patches on the hemisphere but varies over the infinite plane.

Comment: I can’t upvote yet, but thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome!  If a better answer hasn't been posted in 24 hours or so, you can "accept" this answer by clicking the green check mark next to it.